# How to set mail subject using variable and ensure attachment is not included in email body

Tags: linux, email, solaris, aix, mailx

I have the following shell script fragment.

```
var_name='ZZPCI'
for emailadd in `cat /tmp/email_list.tmp`
do
   subject_text="Subject with Var Name "$var_name
   subj_text_novar="Subject without Var Name"
   email_mssge="this is the message with variable name "$var_name
   echo "$email_mssge"|mailx -a /tmp/my_report.txt -s "$subject_text" "$emailadd"
   echo "$email_mssge"|mailx -a /tmp/my_report.txt -s "$subj_text_novar" "$emailadd"
done
```

What it does is 
a. Sets the variable var_name
b. Reads through the list of email addresses stored in /tmp/email_list.tmp
c. Compiles and sends an email with /tmp/my_report.txt (plain text file) as an attachment

The script is intended to run on a number of different servers, so var_name will change with each server.
The mail command with $subj_text_novar, (does not include $var_name in the subject string), sends the email correctly .
However the mail command with $subject_text which does include $var_name places the contents of the attachment into the main body of the email.
As far as I can make out, it is the actual $-sign causing the problem because hardcoding the var_name value into the string is fine but I don't see why because surely var_name is just a concatenated string
So, how can I set the subject for mail so it includes $var_name and my text file is sent as an attachment?

I am running this on SuSE 11.3 but the solution ideally needs to work on AIX 6.1 and HP UX11.31 as well

Regards

Comment: Quote the variables. For example, `subject_text="Subject with Var Name $var_name"`. Do you need to send a separate message to each recipient in `/tmp/email_list.tmp`? If not, you can discard the loop and put `$(cat /tmp/email_list.tmp)` in place of `"$emailadd"` on the two `mailx` command lines

Comment: beware: the -a flag to mailx may not exist on your AIX and/or HPUX machines.

Comment: Thanks to roaima for the answer.  In fact I had tried this before without joy.  But roaima's comment made me re-evaluate and in the context of the shell fragment yes it worked.  However I was actually deriving var_name from an Oracle database, (probably I should've mentioned it but to be honest I didn't think that was the issue).  Anyway   by doing  var_name=`echo $dbs_value`   I was able to employ roaima's solution.

Comment: And thanks Jeff Schaller about AIX & HP.  I'll investigate both OS's to see if there are alternatives

Answer (score 0):

I have something for you using heirloom-mailx:

```
enviaremail() {
values=$(echo "$@" | tr -d '\n')
listargs=()
listargs+=($values)
heirloom-mailx $( attachment=""
for (( a = 5; a < ${#listargs[@]}; a++ )); do
attachment=$(echo "-a ${listargs[a]} ")
echo "${attachment}"
done) -v -s "${titulo}" \
-S smtp-use-starttls \
-S ssl-verify=ignore \
-S smtp-auth=login \
-S smtp=smtp://$1 \
-S from="${2}" \
-S smtp-auth-user=$3 \
-S smtp-auth-password=$4 \
-S ssl-verify=ignore \
$5 < ${cuerpo}
}
```

function call:
enviaremail smtp.mailserver:port from_address authuser 'pass' destination list of attachments separated by space

In addition please remember to define externally the $titulo (subject) and $cuerpo (body) of the email prior to using the function.
You can put the function as a script (mailsend.sh) in the path and then just use it in your scripts with source or place it in your .bashrc file.

Best Regards